# How can I return multiple values from a for loop?

Tags: rust

I will rewrite my previous, and unclear, question. My problem is when I try to return a value from a for loop.

That's works fine:

```rust
fn main() {
    counter(5, 8);
}

fn counter(start: u32, end: u32) {
    for n in start..=end {
        println!("{}", n);
    }
}
```

And that doesn't work:

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = counter(5, 8);
    println!("{}", result);
}

fn counter(start: u32, end: u32) -> u32 {
    for n in start..=end {
        n
    }
}
```

And I try a lot of things and I can't make it work. I hope someone can help me to understand why.

Comment: Hi Aitor, welcome to StackOverflow! As a tip: you just need the inner `for` loop, and you could just print the desired output instead of trying to return the string from within the loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Would you like to return a vector of strings from the function? In this case, you should use the return type `Vec<String>`. Or would you like to print the strings in each iteration? In this case you should use something like `println!()` to print them. In any case, you likely want to remove the infinite `loop` around the for loop.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers and the welcome :) 
What I need is to return a value from a for loop. I tried to simplify the code to ask the question but it was unclear, sorry.
I will follow your advice (remove the infinite loop) and see if I can re-ask the question.

Comment: @AitorZaldua if you need to return the string, why not `return s`? `for` loops don't have values, and `loop` only has a value through `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a function like this

```
fn counter(start: u32, end: u32) -> u32
```

then you tell the compiler that it is supposed to return a single `u32` value, i.e. a single unsigned integer number.

Your for loop iterates over a bunch of numbers, but it can only return one of them. You could change the return type of your function to return a `Vec<u32>`, a vector of `u32` which is a data structure that can store a whole bunch of `u32` values:

```
fn counter(start: u32, end: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    (start..=end).collect()
}
```

Alternatively, you could also tell the compiler that the result is an *iterator* over `u32` values:

```
fn counter(start: u32, end: u32) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> {
    start..=end
}
```

The iterator lazily produces the values from `start` to `end`, and you can iterate over it in the calling code, e.g.

```
for i in counter(1, 10) {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

prints the numbers from one to ten.

Comment: Thanks Sven, that´s exactly what I needed to know,

Comment: @AitorZaldua if this answer solved your problem, consider *accepting* it to reward users for helping you out

Comment: Ok, thankyou, kmdreko, I didn´t know that I had to check the answer (sorry Sven)...done.